# angular *ngIf doesn't work together with fxFlex.lg and fxFlex.xl

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a `div` with a `*ngIf` conditional and `fxFlex.lg="30" fxFlex.xl="50"`responsive layout values:

```
<div class="project-test__element" *ngIf="myCondition()" fxFlex.lg="30" fxFlex.xl="50" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
    Test fxFlex.lg and fxFlex.xl
</div>
```

and the following style is being applied to my `div`:

```
place-content: center flex-end;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
flex: 1 1 100%;
max-width: 30%; (30% when lg and 50% when xl)
```

But when the user change from a **HD** resolution to **Full HD** resolution, the `max-width` prop is being removed. The solution was: Separate the `*ngIf` conditional in a new `div` above the `div` with my `fxFlex` values.

**why** `*ngIf` **and** `fxFlex` *from** [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) **doesn't work together?**

Versions:

```
Angular: 8.1.3
@angular/flex-layout: 8.0.0-beta.26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Angualar 9+ because we have the new Ivy template compiler.

Usually whenever you use a structural directive (that has a *) you can think of it as the item that the directive is put on is wrapped inside a ng-template tag which is used as the template for creating the item:

```
<div *ngIf="hide">HELLO</div>
```

will look something like

```
<ng-template *ngIf="hide">
  <div>HELLO</div>
</ng-template>
```

In previous versions of angular everything that you put on the element that has the structural directive is automatically transferred to the ng-template tag. That's why you have to wrap the element as you did.

The better solution is to just use the `ngIf` without the `*` and with the `ng-template` tag like the example I showed you and put the other directives on the div element itself.

I also suggest that you upgrade to at least Angular 9 in order to resolve this issue and also have all the benefits that we have in the newer versions.

Comment: Thx for all the explanation about the problem, it's really clear now.